# how do I make this android material look nice?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

I want to slightly nudge and adjust this style only slightly .. does anyone have any ideas how I might go about it ? I am using `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'`

[image]

- I would like to place the grey "underlay" under the box exactly
- I would like to be able to alter the colour of the border (either way focussed or unfocussed)
- I would like to alter the hint colour, the superpositonal label colour and the text typed colour if possible

here is my code:

```
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                style="@style/TextTheme"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="This is a Hint"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>                

        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

then we have `res\values\styles.xml`

```
 <resources>
    <style name="TextTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">#2962FF</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#0039CB</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorError">#F44336</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">#212121</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">#212121</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/nice_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

finally in `res\drawable\nice_text.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:top="5dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4c5a67" />
            <solid android:color="#4c5a67" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="4dp" android:bottom="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4c5a67" />
            <solid android:color="#4c5a67" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: `fill_parent` it's not 2008 anymore, use match_parent

Answer (score 0):

> Provide smaller customization to TextInputLayout. Simply use FilledBox style

I think this style would help you somehow:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving paddingTop to TextInputEditText same as layerlist item's top attribute which is in your case 5dp
so, code will be like

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:hint="This is a Hint"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove background of TextInputLayout by using below

```
android:background="@null"
```